Do new items need to be kashered?
Do brand new kitchen items (e.g. crockpots, glassware, etc.) need to be kashered? What's the source?

No.  Kashering is for removing traces of non-kosher foods previously cooked in them.  If the items have never been used, then there are no traces, and kashering is not needed.
Tevilah (immersion in a natural body of water or in a mikvah) of the object, on the other hand, would be needed, if they were manufactured or retailed by a non-Jew.
See here for more information about tevilat keilim.
